# Filtering table records based on latest date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Similar questions have been asked already, but I could find exactly what I am looking for. Since I am new to SQL I could not derive my solution from similar questions.

Coming the my problem, I have a table that store insurance details of customers shown as below

[image]

There may be multiple customer_ids under a company_id. As you can see in the image, first 5 columns in two rows can have similar data, except due_date.I want to write a query that returns latest insurance  details (ie, unique records for each customer with max(due_date)) of every customer under each company. ie, the query should return the following records

```
(100,548754,nia,1000000,Banglore,24-02-2020)
(100,254475,lpa,1000000,Delhi,24-02-2020)
(103,958740,cba,1000000,Banglore,24-06-2021)
```

I tried with different queries, but all of the return duplicate records

Comment: You want to select rows that are `DISTINCT ON (company_id,customer_id)`. And you will need an `ORDER BY` clause that uses `due_date` in addition to the first two fields. See the [SELECT-documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

Comment: I want to select all columns, not just company_id,customer_id. How can I do that using DISTINCT @clamp

Comment: Simply put them into your select list. (Did you read the document I linked to?)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (company_id,customer_id) * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY company_id,customer_id,due_date DESC
```

If you specify `DISTINCT ON ()` in your SELECT statement, you will get the first row of each set where the expressions given to DISTINCT ON () have equal values.
You need the `ORDER BY` to make sure, that the first row in each of these sets is the one with the latest date.

Comment: It would help readers if you added further explanation to your answer so they could see the value in your answer compared to the other solution choices. Use [edit] to improve your answer.